# Duplicate Record run time error for VBA code

Tags: database, vba, ms-access, ms-access-2013

I am currently working within Access 2013.

The problem that I have is that I am trying to duplicate a record from the main form to a subform with a button.

My tables consist of:

```
tbl40_1                      tbl40_1_changes

ID (PK)                      ID (PK)
System_Name                  40_1_ID (FK)
Configuration_Type           System_Name
Configuration_ID             Configuration_Type
Reference_Document           Configuration_ID 
Approval_Authority           Reference_Document
Approval_Mechanism           Approval_Authority
Item_Location                Approval_Mechanism 
Custodian                    Item_Location  
                             Custodian
```

The current code that I have for the button consist of:

```
Private Sub Duplicate_Click()

Dim strInsert
Dim db As DAO.Database

StrInsert = "INSERT INTO tbl40_1_changes_subform (ID, [System_Name], [Configuration_Type], [Configuration_ID], [Reference_Document], [Approval_Authority], [Approval_Mechanism], [Item_Location], [Custodian]" & _
            "SELECT ID, [System_Name], [Configuration_Type], [Configuration_ID], [Reference_Document], [Approval_Authority], [Approval_Mechanism], [Item_Location], [Custodian]" & _
            "FROM frm40_1" & _
            "WHERE [40_1_ID] = " & Me.tbl40_1_changes_subform.Form.txt40_1_ID

Set db = CurrentDb()

db.Execute strInsert, dbFailOnError
Set db = Nothing


End Sub
```

When I click on the button I am getting a Run-time error for [StrInsert = "INSERT INTO", "Select", "From", "Where"]. I am not for sure what is wrong within this code as it is highlighting this entire piece of code.

Comment: you forgot to close the first line with `)`

Comment: Include `Debug.Print StrInsert`, run the code, and then inspect the `INSERT` statement in the Immediate window.  (Ctrl+g will take you there.)  You need to match this pattern: `INSERT INTO TableName (<field list>) ...`  You must include both parentheses around `<field list>` --- looks like yours is missing the second.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing spaces at your line breaks.

Add a `Debug.Print StrInsert` to see it.

And, as Hynek Bernard wrote, the INSERT clause is missing the closing `)`

Try

```
StrInsert = "INSERT INTO tbl40_1_changes (ID, [System_Name], [Configuration_Type], [Configuration_ID], [Reference_Document], [Approval_Authority], [Approval_Mechanism], [Item_Location], [Custodian])" & _
            " SELECT ID, [System_Name], [Configuration_Type], [Configuration_ID], [Reference_Document], [Approval_Authority], [Approval_Mechanism], [Item_Location], [Custodian]" & _
            " FROM frm40_1" & _
            " WHERE [40_1_ID] = " & Me.tbl40_1_changes_subform.Form.txt40_1_ID

Debug.Print StrInsert   ' Ctrl+G shows Debug output
```

**Edit**

I think your WHERE clause is very off. You are copying from `frm40_1` (on the main form) to `tbl40_1_changes` on the subform, right?

And if `tbl40_1_changes.ID` is an Autonumber, you can't set it.

Then you'll need something like

```
StrInsert = "INSERT INTO tbl40_1_changes (40_1_ID, [System_Name], [Configuration_Type], [Configuration_ID], [Reference_Document], [Approval_Authority], [Approval_Mechanism], [Item_Location], [Custodian])" & _
            " SELECT ID, [System_Name], [Configuration_Type], [Configuration_ID], [Reference_Document], [Approval_Authority], [Approval_Mechanism], [Item_Location], [Custodian]" & _
            " FROM tbl40_1" & _
            " WHERE ID = " & Me.ID
```

Comment: Hello Andre, thanks for the response. I copied your code and I still getting the same error code (Run-time error `2465`: Application - defined or object - defined error).

Comment: Please double-check that error, @Orange56.  The message for Access error #2465 starts with *"Microsoft Access can't find the field ..."*

Comment: @Orange56: edited target table name. If it still fails, please post the full Debug output. And read [How to debug dynamic SQL in VBA](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/418960/managing-and-debugging-sql-queries-in-ms-access/1099570#1099570)

Comment: @HansUp I have check the Access error #2465 and it is displaying ("application-defined or object-defined error), not for sure why. When I search the code in google it is displaying "Microsoft Access can't find the field".

Comment: @Orange56: Also, if `40_1_ID` is a foreign key, you will have to insert it too. I strongly suggest building your query in the query designer, and only when it is finished and working, copy the SQL back to VBA.

Comment: I don't understand why that happens, @Orange56, but do you still get an error after changing `tbl40_1_changes_subform`  to `tbl40_1_changes`?

Comment: @HansUp it is still giving me the error message for some reason.

Comment: @Orange56: see edit, I think there was much more wrong with your initial query than I thought at first.

Comment: @Orange56 I think your best strategy is to follow Andre's earlier advice.  Build a valid `INSERT` in the query designer. I would do it as a parameter query, but that's not required.  Anyway, once you have it working, adjust your VBA code to produce the same `INSERT` ... and verify it by checking the output from `Debug.Print StrInsert`

Comment: @Andre, yes I am copying from frm40_1 to the subform tbl40_1_changes. The data type for (40_1_ID) is a number, data type for tbl40_1_changes (ID) is an autonumber, and the data type for tbl40_1 (ID) is a autonumber.

Comment: @Orange56: Then the last edit should do it, assuming `tbl40_1.ID` is represented by a field `ID` on the main form.

Comment: @Andre thank you that code is working great.. Now I am getting an error code (Run-Time error #3131 "Syntax error in FROM clause"). When I debug the code it is showing db.Execute strInsert, dbFailOnError is wrong.

Comment: Copy&Paste the Debug.Print of `StrInsert` into the query designer (SQL view). Switch to Design view. This will get more detailed error information.